# hidden pictures in Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 are gone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-10.1

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (Kitkat)
I hidden some pictures then it just says "unable to hide item" but it will be gone on the gallery so I tried to look for it on "My Files" but I still cannot see the pictures. I tried to click settings>show hidden files but i still cannot view my files. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All Samsung gallery is equipped with a hide item option which moves the picture you choose to hide to a separate folder. It might be possible that you could have deleted the folder or moved it away. The folder is named .hide in hidden folders in Device Storage. In case of any problem you can go to it and move the pictures away. Please do not delete system folders as they can be useful.